# How do you install an iTunes Visualizer in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, visualization

How do you install any visualizer other than the default visualizer that ships with iTunes 10 in Windows 7.  I've tried placing qtz files in my `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\iTunes Plug-ins` folder and restarting iTunes, but of course no other visualizers can be selected.

Common visualizers that I would like to install include those [found here](http://gigaom.com/apple/14-free-itunes-visualizers/)

I'm of course aware that some of these are Mac OS only due to library dependencies - I would still like to know if it's possible to install any visualizer other than the default for iTunes in Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest downloading one from [here](http://itunes.pluginsworld.com/index.php?directory=apple&software=itunes&category=28) which is compatible with windows and see if you get the same error. You'll notice the ones which are compatible with windows have the correct extension.